# redirect in Javascript or Jquery with many variables

Tags: javascript, redirect

Good day to every one

I want to redirect to a page in Javascript but I want to send some variables in the same time
I tried a simple redirection in JS using window.location.replace but only on varaible is sent
the link is cut after the first "&"

How can I solve this issue
I want to do in in JS or Jquery because my page is called in a DIV

Thanks for your help

The code I use

```
<?php $pagetogoto=$_REQUEST["page"];?>

<script>
window.location.replace("<?php echo $pagetogoto;?>"); 
</script>
```

Comment: I would prefer to store this in the `localStorage` if it's persistent values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way :

```
window.location.replace("<?php echo $pagetogoto.'?var1=hello&var2=world';?>");
```

Comment: The thing is I dont know what is in $pagetogo, so I cannot do it this way

Comment: $pagetogoto can be any page, so I cannot use your solution I donr know which variables are sent